# CleanName not cleaning " in Excel VBA?

Tags: regex, string, vba, excel

I'm updating the question to show what I have already, before adding in lines from here...

```
Function CleanName(strName As String) As String
'will clean part # name so it can be made into valid folder name
'may need to add more lines to get rid of other characters

    CleanName = Replace(strName, "/", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "*", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, ".", "")
    CleanName = Replace(strName, "\", "")

End Function
```

Comment: Hi Matt. I'ved edited my answer based on your updated post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than multiple string replacements you could use a [regexp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300%28v=VS.84%29.aspx)

```
Function KillChars(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
.Global = True
.Pattern = "[\/\*\.\\""""]+"
KillChars = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```

Comment: + 1 Supah! When I saw ooo solution, I thought of giving a Regexp example but then decided against it as the question was already solved :D However this is the best answer till now

Comment: Here is a complete list which can be added to the above `.Pattern` 
    < (less than)
    > (greater than)
    : (colon)
    " (double quote)
    / (forward slash)
    \ (backslash)
    | (vertical bar or pipe)
    ? (question mark)
    * (asterisk)

Comment: +1 Much quicker but only if you don't `Set objRegex = `every time the function is called :)

Comment: +1 Cleaner, quicker. Love it. I need to use this more :) Thanks brettdj

Comment: @oo thanks :). I wrote this assuming it was a UDF. If the core code was processing many strings from an array, range etc, then yes it would be cleaner to embed the function within the main sub. Although for a UDF I don't think it will make a huge difference to the time overhead.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

Matt, to your updated post, change the code to this:

```
Function CleanName(strName As String) As String
'will clean part # name so it can be made into valid folder name
'may need to add more lines to get rid of other characters

    CleanName = Replace(strName, "/", "") '-> only use strName the first time, since you are passing that string to the Function
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "*", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, ".", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "\", "") '-> if you use strName here, you lose your first 3 replacments
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, """", "") '-> this is the correct syntax to remove the "
    '-> to Sid's point, this should work too
    'CleanName = Replace(CleanName, Chr(34), "")

End Function
```

Since others are answering, I'll change my comment to an answer to join the party!

Try

`CleanName = Replace(CleanName, """", "")`

You need to surround the quote in double quotes to tell VBA you want to look for the actual actual quote and not the special character it automatically recognizes.  *(Daniel Cook's comment below touches on it as well.)*

For the benefit of others, CleanName is a custom function that cleans strings of unwanted characters. See this link for more information: [CleanName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803834/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-folder-and-sub-folders-in-excel-vba)

Comment: + 1 I saw your comment after I posted my answer and was wondering as to why you posted it as a comment as it is a valid answer :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout -> I guess I was thinking it was a such a simple thing, a comment was easier, but I see how that can kind of take away from the effectiveness of searches on SO for others to see.

Comment: Nitpicking... If you were to "surround the quote in double quotes" then you would need to provide 5 quotation marks to indicate 1 quotation mark as a string (which as you probably know, would be auto-corrected by the IDE to be 6 quotation marks). The four quotes are as ordered. #1: Opening quotation mark indicating the start of a string. #2 & #3: Double quotation mark noting that you want a quotation mark in the string. #4: Closing quotation mark indicating the end of the string.

Comment: @Daniel ... Thanks. I forgot to update my wording to be more accurate. Doing now.

Comment: except if I do """"", I get an Expected: list separator or ) error message.

Comment: @MattRidge - I fixed that a while back. Timing might have gotten crossed. Anyway, I updated my answer based on your updated post. Check out my notes. They will help you for sure :)

Comment: @MattRidge Yeah... It auto corrects if listed as in an assignment like: `string = """""` as a single line. A rule of thumb is that you need an even number of quotation marks in VBA.

Answer (score 3):

Paste this in a module

```
Public Function CleanName(rng As Range) As Variant
    CleanName = Replace(rng.Value, Chr(34), "")
End Function
```

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CleanName(rng As Range) As Variant
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Dim vVal As Variant

    vVal = rng.Value
    vVal = Replace(vVal, Chr(34), "") ' "
    vVal = Replace(vVal, Chr(42), "") ' *
    vVal = Replace(vVal, Chr(46), "") ' .
    vVal = Replace(vVal, Chr(47), "") ' /
    vVal = Replace(vVal, Chr(92), "") ' \

    CleanName = vVal
Whoa:
End Function
```

Comment: You are telling me the best way to get this to work is to write the Character value? Thanks again. Sometimes I wonder how people write in this code without going crazy...

Comment: You can either use Chr(34) or like @nutsch suggested `""""`

Comment: @MattRidge. is it the best way, I don't know. But it is one way. My answer below and nutsch's answer will also work. See my explanation for how to work with the quotes.

Comment: Updated my question, to show what is being used. I'd like to use your Sid, but I don't think it will work.

Comment: @MattRidge: Whoa! where did the rest come from :D. I can update my answer to accommodate the rest if you want.

Comment: @SiddharthRout yes I'm using your code you originally gave me a long time ago, but now I'm running into another issue I can't seem to get rid of on my own.

Comment: @SiddharthRout his answer is still wrong. I am getting errors... as posted above in a sec.

Comment: @MattRidge -> Please tell me where my code craps out? It works like a charm for me. If it's not working for you, I'd love to know where.

Comment: I got it working, the issue was that the code below took out a \ when it shouldn't of, and joined the folder names together. I got it working, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative :)

```
Option Explicit

    Function CleanName(ByRef str As String) As String
    Dim removeChars As String
    Dim i As Long
        removeChars = "/*."""

        For i = 1 To Len(removeChars)
            str = Replace(str, Mid(removeChars, i, 1), vbNullString)
        Next i
        CleanName = str

    End Function
```

and to test

```
Sub Test()
Dim messyString As String

    messyString = "/*It Works!""."
    Debug.Print CleanName(messyString)

End Sub
```