# Creating folder with cell as name

Tags: vba, excel, create-directory

As I create a project number using the below code, I need to create a folder with the title as the new project number in the following path: `W:\My system\me\my work\PROJECTS\Projects\Reliability`, I know the code needs to be placed after (`.Cells(MyRow, "Q").Value = Sheets("Tracker").Cells(3, "E").Value   'project NUMBER`) as title of the new project will be placed in "active column 17" once the below code is completed

So I have this code which checks if a cell is empty and when prompted to create a project number, This works fine but I'm not sure how to add code to create the new folder in the above folder

```
Sub MyFileprojectTF()
    'Detemine to open or create report.
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim MyNewFile As String
    Dim MySht, MyWBK As String
    Dim MyRow As Integer
    MyRow = ActiveCell.Row
    MySht = ActiveSheet.Name
    MyWBK = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    If ActiveCell.Column = 17 Then
        If ActiveCell.Value <> "" Then 'if cell in the is empty
            MyFileprojectOpenTF
        Else
            OpenTemplate 'opens template tracker for new project number

            With Workbooks("project.xls").Sheets("Tracker")
                .Cells(9, "B").Value = Workbooks(MyWBK).Sheets(MySht).Cells(MyRow, "H").Value  'Project
                .Cells(10, "B").Value = Workbooks(MyWBK).Sheets(MySht).Cells(MyRow, "J").Value  'Customer
                .Cells(2, "G").Value = Workbooks(MyWBK).Sheets(MySht).Cells(MyRow, "P").Value  'tracker
                .Cells(14, "E").Value = Workbooks(MyWBK).Sheets(MySht).Cells(MyRow, "O").Value  'tech
                .Cells(15, "E").Value = Workbooks(MyWBK).Sheets(MySht).Cells(MyRow, "N").Value  'FILE REF
                .Cells(25, "A").Value = Workbooks(MyWBK).Sheets(MySht).Cells(MyRow, "L").Value  'Description
            End With

            '***********************************
            NewProjectGSRTF
            UpDateMyDataBaseTF
            '***********************************

            With Workbooks(MyWBK).Sheets(MySht)
                .Cells(MyRow, "Q").Value = Sheets("Tracker").Cells(3, "E").Value   'project NUMBER
            End With

            ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
            Workbooks(MyWBK).Save
        End If
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: FileSystemObject for creating folders? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033820/filesystemobject-createfolder-to-create-directory-and-subdirectories   or MkDir

Comment: unrelatred observation:  you know that `ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True`  `ActiveWorkbook.Close` closes the current workbook *without* saving it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on the two version I mentioned in comments.  Update Activesheet with correct sheet and range with correct cell to collect folder name from. Currently have default `"Testing"` name created in case cell is empty where getting name from.

**1) MKDIR**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MyFileprojectTF()

    Dim startPath As String
    Dim myName As String

    startPath = "W:\My system\me\my work\PROJECTS\Projects\Reliability"
    myName = ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Text        ' Change as required to cell holding the folder title

    If myName = vbNullString Then myName = "Testing"

    Dim folderPathWithName As String
    folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName

    If Dir(folderPathWithName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        MkDir folderPathWithName
    Else
       MsgBox "Folder already exists"
       Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

**2) FSO**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MyFileprojectTF()

    Dim startPath As String
    Dim myName As String

    startPath = "W:\My system\me\my work\PROJECTS\Projects\Reliability"
    myName = ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Text        ' Change as required to cell holding the folder title

    If myName = vbNullString Then myName = "Testing"

    Dim folderPathWithName As String
    folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName

    If Dir(folderPathWithName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
        Dim fso As Object
        Set fso = CreateObject("FileSystemObject")
        fso.CreateFolder folderPathWithName
    Else
       MsgBox "Folder already exists"
       Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`MkDir`** create a folder using VBA:

```
MkDir "FolderName"
```

...creates a folder named "`FolderName`" in the current directory, or:

```
MkDir "c:\users\bob\desktop\FolderName"
```

...creates a folder named "`FolderName`" on Bob's desktop.

To create folder `W:\My system\me\my work\PROJECTS\Projects\Reliability`, use:

```
MkDir "W:\My system\me\my work\PROJECTS\Projects\Reliability"
```

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/mkdir-statement) (but there's not much more to say).

Comment: So by adding this after the line of code .Cells(MyRow, "Q").Value = Sheets("Tracker").Cells(3, "E").Value, this will add a folder in the dir with the cell value in active column 17?

Comment: does `Sheets("Tracker").Cells(3, "E").Value` contain the folder name?  (A value similar to `W:\My system\me\my work\PROJECTS\Projects\Reliability`?)  If so, then yes, but change the code to `MkDir Sheets("Tracker").Cells(3, "E").Value`.