# Loop to save worksheet in new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run through a specific sheet (from & to) save those ws as a new file in a folder, if the folder doesn't exist then create.

I'm able to do it to one sheet.

```vb
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
If Range("F3").Value = "" Then
Windows("Import OT.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Cash").Select
Dim filename101 As String
Dim path101 As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
path101 = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Dropbox\A271\5 Oppgjor\" & 2020 & "\"
filename101 = Range("B1").Value & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path101 & Range("A2") & "\" & Range("A1") & " " & filename101,xlOpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else
Cells.Select
Range("F3").Activate
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Dim Path1 As String
Dim fpathname1 As String
Path1 = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Dropbox\A271\4 Lonnslipper\"
fpathname1 = Path1 & Range("F3") & "\" & Range("F2") & " " & Range("B3") & ".xlsx"

path01 = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Dropbox\A271\4 Lonnslipper\" & Range("F3")
Dim path001 As String
Dim Folder As String

Folder = Dir(path01, vbDirectory)
If Folder = vbNullString Then
VBA.FileSystem.MkDir (path01)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=fpathname1, FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Sheets("Cash").Select
Else
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=fpathname1, FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Sheets("Cash").Select

End If
End If
End Sub
```

I want this as a loop is because I have a few tens of sheets. For it to work I think I need to write it specific time, but with loop I learned I don't need to do that.

Excel file sheet
[image]

https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=AF6FF2618C09AC74!29027&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!AHcJjYCu8D0NTNY

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment where you wrote the steps:

Read the comments

Try to run the code using `F8` key and see where you need to change it.

As you're learning, please note to first write the steps in plain <s>English</s> Norsk and then develop your code.

See how I just followed your steps with readable code.

---

**Code:**

```
Public Sub GenerateCustomersFiles()
    
    ' 1) Active sheet (oppgjør 1-20)
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    For Each targetSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        
        ' Check only sheets with string in name
        If InStr(targetSheet.Name, "Oppgjør") > 0 Then
            ' 2) look if value in F3 is empty
            If targetSheet.Range("F3").Value = vbNullString Then
                    
                ' 3) if it is, do select "cash" sheet and save this file (its name and path are given above what it should be named)
                Dim fileName As String
                Dim filePath As String
                Dim folderPath As String
                folderPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Dropbox\A271\5 Oppgjor\" & 2020 & "\"

                fileName = targetSheet.Range("B1").Value & ".xlsx"
                filePath = folderPath & targetSheet.Range("A2") & "\" & targetSheet.Range("A1") & " " & fileName
                
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Cash").Select
                ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
                
            Else
                ' 4) if it doesn't, do open selected sheet to a new workbook and save that in clients name folder (folder and path given above in code section)
                folderPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Dropbox\A271\4 Lonnslipper\" & targetSheet.Range("F3")
                
                fileName = targetSheet.Range("F2") & " " & targetSheet.Range("B3") & ".xlsx"
                filePath = folderPath & "\" & fileName
                
                ' 5) check if clients folder exist or not for the file to be saved in.
                ' if folder doesnt exist,
                ' create new and save file there.
                CreateFoldersInPath folderPath
                
                ' if folder exist just save the file there
                Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
                Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
                targetSheet.Copy before:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(1)
                targetWorkbook.SaveAs filePath, 51
                targetWorkbook.Close
            End If
        End If
    
    Next targetSheet

End Sub

' Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31034201/1521579
Private Sub CreateFoldersInPath(ByVal targetFolderPath As String)

    Dim strBuildPath As String
    Dim varFolder As Variant

    If Right(targetFolderPath, 1) = "\" Then targetFolderPath = Left(targetFolderPath, Len(targetFolderPath) - 1)
    
    For Each varFolder In Split(targetFolderPath, "\")
        If Len(strBuildPath) = 0 Then
            strBuildPath = varFolder & "\"
        Else
            strBuildPath = strBuildPath & varFolder & "\"
        End If
        If Len(Dir(strBuildPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strBuildPath
    Next varFolder

    'The full folder path has been created regardless of nested subdirectories
    'Continue with your code here

End Sub
```

Let me know how it goes

Comment: thanks for the help. I will try it out. but what i didnt understand was, you have written 3 times End sub does that mean all of those are different codes or is that one code?
As for my code; The code i have above goes as follow; it saves sheets to a folder and if there isnt any folder to that name then it will create a new one and save it in there. but my code only run for one sheet and not all those i have.

Comment: what i was looking for help with was; A code which will do exactly said above; open and save specific sheet to a new workbook in the said location which is customers folder, Range ("F3") thats where those customers names are written and the folders name will be it. create a new one if there isnt one for this customer. instead of writing this code individually for each sheet all this will run through a loop instead.

Comment: I'll try to take a look into it this weekend.

Comment: @excelnoob298 questions: 1) You say that customer's names are in F3, are they separated by commas or how do you get them from that single cell? Also, 2) it's not clear what workbook are you opening, the one named "Import OT.xlsm"? and 3) I understand that customer's name is the folder's name, file name is the same for all customers?

Comment: 1) No they are not separated. Full names comes up. so my first half of code which is from activesheet to "Else" Look at F3 cell to see if the cell is empty or not. if it is then code after "Else" will not run instead it will go back to a sheet called "Cash". if there is a value(name) there then the file will save it with the name given to it in filename and save it in path(folder name for monthly reports)

Comment: 2) after "Else" If the cell F3 has a value then each individual customer sheet will open in a new workbook to save it as a new file  with its name given in fpathname1 code saved in path1 which is the customer folder. 3) fpathname is the customers name. if the value has "ricardo", "jhonny", "david" or any customer name in it the file name will name it self after that followed by month name which is B3 in that customers folder.

Comment: path01 and the code afterwards is for it to check if a customer has folder or not. for it to create a new folder if not or if it is then save the file there. 
The problem with this code is this whole code is for only 1 sheet and i have 30 sheets in my file. to write this code 30 times changing all the path and file names becomes confusing to have 100 different pathnames.

I read that loop is the best option here but since im new to vba coding i dont know how to do it. i will try to add the file up there, you can check it out to understand the cell values im choosing. its not in english :-)

Comment: ok. maybe with the file link would be easier

Comment: Im new to this website so i dont know how to upload the excel file or link it here. the file is saved in my desktop. i dont have OneDrive. thats why i wrote the whole code with a picture above (under the code i wrote named "excel file sheet")  and tried to explain the problem i have and with your help finding a solution for this :)

Comment: [Edit] your question and share a link. OneDrive is a free service

Comment: Done. you can check it out now. since the file is not in english i can explain what each sheet is for. "skiftlapper" is where i upload my csv data. "plukk" is where the data is sorted into what i want.  if you download the file you will find a button on same sheet named "Press" thats just for what i want to click so macro will run. "cash" is like a summary of everything. "oppgjør" is where i pluck in each individual customers data.

Comment: Read the file, but your instructions are pretty confusing. I can get your're not an English speaker, but you'd have to try harder if you want this to be done: Something like: 1) Activate sheet X, then 2) look if value in F3 is empty, 3) if it is, do X or 4) if it doesn't do Y. Otherwise I'm unable to understand you.

Comment: sorry for that i will try to do it just like you explained. 
1) Active sheet (oppgjør 1-20), then 2) look if value in F3 is empty, 3) if it is, do select "cash" sheet and save this file (its name and path are given above what it should be named) or 4) if it doesn't, do open selected sheet to a new workbook and save that in clients name folder (folder and path given above in code section). 5) check if clients folder exist or not for the file to be saved in. if folder doesnt exist, create new and save file there. if folder exist just save the file there.

Comment: Pls check the answer with the updated code

Comment: The code got stopped when ever it was saving the file. i stumbled upon few problems. 
1) the code you wrote in nr 3 where you are specifying the location it seems to get it from wrong sheet. instead of getting path and file name from "cash" sheet it gets from oppgjør sheet. 
2) the code in nr 5 "CreateFoldersInPath folderPath" when i run it says "sub or function not defined".
3) i tried to remove "CreateFoldersInPath folderPath" and run the code. the new path defined as lønnslipper is not used intead it saves the file in previos folder path (oppgjør) and not new one (lønnslipper).

Comment: Kindly I remind you that the philosophy of this site is to help you write the code. I suggest that you step into the code line by line using `F8` key and try to adjust it to fit your needs. You have all the elements to figure it out. If you stumble into a specific problem, I suggest that you post a new question with the error and the complete information for someone here to help you.