Create a full folder path if it doesn't exist
I need to create a full folder path including multiple folders if the directory doesn't exist
I have found the below code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31034201/22145621
however it only works if the drive is referenced as a letter and not the full drive path such as
\\Servername\Users\TEST\Downloads\BIRDS\TEST1\SUBFOLDER\
Sub tgr()

    Dim strFolderPath As String
    Dim strBuildPath As String
    Dim varFolder As Variant

    strFolderPath = "C:\Users\TEST\Downloads\BIRDS\TEST1\SUBFOLDER\" & Format(Date, "yyyy") & "\" & Format(Date, "M") & ". " & Format(Date, "mmm") & "\"

    If Right(strFolderPath, 1) = "\" Then strFolderPath = Left(strFolderPath, Len(strFolderPath) - 1)
    For Each varFolder In Split(strFolderPath, "\")
        If Len(strBuildPath) = 0 Then
            strBuildPath = varFolder & "\"
        Else
            strBuildPath = strBuildPath & varFolder & "\"
        End If
        If Len(Dir(strBuildPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir strBuildPath
    Next varFolder

    'The full folder path has been created regardless of nested subdirectories
    'Continue with your code here

End Sub

How can i make it work with the full drive name instead of the letter?
I cannot use MkDir as this will only create one folder not multiple.

You could temporarily assign a drive letter to the main folder and then use this code to create the path structure

basically this is going to be used on a shared drive and each user may have mapped it differently, so i need it to work with the full drive path. The drive path in the above is just an example

This create any missing folders:
Sub CreateFoldersIfNotExist(ByVal FolderPath As String)
    Dim FolderParts() As String
    Dim CurrentPath As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Split the folder path into parts
    FolderParts = Split(FolderPath, "\")
    
    ' Rebuild the path and create each folder if it doesn't exist
    CurrentPath = FolderParts(0) & "\"
    For i = 1 To UBound(FolderParts)
        CurrentPath = CurrentPath & FolderParts(i) & "\"
        If Dir(CurrentPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir CurrentPath
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


Here is a function that uses pure VBA to create a folder structure. This function is defined recursively.
Sub CreateFolderStructure(path As String)
    ' Check if the folder already exists
    If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        ' Extract the parent directory
        Dim parentPath As String
        parentPath = Left(path, InStrRev(path, "\") - 1)
        
        ' Recursively create the parent folders
        If Len(parentPath) > 0 And Len(Dir(parentPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            CreateFolderStructure parentPath
        End If
        
        ' Create the current folder
        MkDir path
    End If
End Sub

Sub TestCreateFolderStructure()
    ' Example usage with a UNC path
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "\\Servername\Users\TEST\Downloads\BIRDS\TEST1\SUBFOLDER\"
    
    ' Call the function to create the folder structure
    CreateFolderStructure folderPath
End Sub

The MkDir function is generally used to create directories on local file systems. While it can handle UNC (Universal Naming Convention) paths, such as \\Servername\Users\TEST\Downloads\BIRDS\TEST1\SUBFOLDER\, there are some considerations and limitations to keep in mind:
Network Permissions: Ensure that the user running the VBA script has the necessary permissions to create directories on the network share. Lack of permissions is a common issue and will result in a runtime error.
Availability: The network share must be accessible at the time the script runs. Any network issues or downtime will prevent the directory from being created.
Path Syntax: Make sure the UNC path is correctly formatted. It should start with \\ followed by the server name and the shared folder.
