# Create sub folders from cell value/s

Tags: excel, subdirectory, filesystemobject, fso, vba

Hi I am attempting to create sub folders using the value in a cell which is "Nikki jules\Fallen Kingdom\night watch" but every time i run the macro it says folder path not found 76. I even tried it Mkdir.

```
  folder1 = Range("G1").Value 'G1 value is Nikki jules\Fallen Kingdom\night watch
        NewFolder = "C:\Users\Paul\Documents\Battle wars\" & folder1
```

so can someone please give me a solution and the reason why it doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: [Here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1039482-creating-sub-folders-using-vba.html) or [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803834/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-folder-and-sub-folders-in-excel-vba?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: can you please give me an example?