# Excel VBA Creates a Folder, Sub Folders and further sub folders

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question that is very similar to some others i have seen on here, but they dont quite answer what i need, or when i have tried them it has caused an error that i dont know how to solve. 
Only being level 5 i can't comment to ask a question.

In excel i have a file that is used for the naming profile for quotation folders.

I have tried to use the answer for: [Create a folder and sub folder in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803834/create-a-folder-and-sub-folder-in-excel-vba) and tweaked it as per the below, but it errors when it gets to `If Functions.FolderExists(path) Then` it says

> Run-time error '424': Object required.

I also need to to create the folder name as per sheet "Data Entry" cell "C44" and "C31", i then need to add subfolders to this which are not referenced in any cell including: 
 1. Customer RFQ
This will have a further subfolder with the name base on "Data Entry" cell "C33"

2. Design Engineering
3. Drawings
4. Costings
5. Schedules
6. Quotation

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you,

```
'requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub MakeFolder()

Dim strFolder As String, strPath As String

strFolder = CleanName(Range("C31")) ' assumes folder name is in C31
strPath = Range("C44") ' assumes path name is in C44

If Not FolderExists(strPath) Then
'Path doesn't exist, so create full path
    FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder
Else
'Path does exist, but no quote folder
    If Not FolderExists(strPath & "\" & strFolder) Then
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder
    End If
End If

End Sub

Function FolderCreate(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderCreate = True
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If Functions.FolderExists(path) Then 'This is the part that doesn't work
    Exit Function
Else
    On Error GoTo DeadInTheWater
    fso.CreateFolder path ' could there be any error with this, like if the path is really screwed up?
    Exit Function
End If

DeadInTheWater:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & path & ". Check the path name and try again."
    FolderCreate = False
    Exit Function

End Function

Function FolderExists(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderExists = False
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExists = True

End Function

Function CleanName(strName As String) As String
'will clean part # name so it can be made into valid folder name
'may need to add more lines to get rid of other characters

    CleanName = Replace(strName, "/", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "*", "")

End Function
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `If fso.FolderExists(path) Then`

Comment: @BigBen WOW! that was really quick! Thank you very much, just for interest, what is the difference between a function and fso? Obviously everyone else who used it knew to change it but being new to this i would have no idea to change it.

Comment: I will point you to the [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) documentation for a thorough explanation.

Comment: @BigBen, really appreciate your help!  Thank you very much, really greatful.

Comment: If you change `Functions.FolderExists(path)` to `FolderExists(path)` it would work, too.  You don't need to preface with `Functions`.  However, that function really isn't needed, just use the solution from @BigBen.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Thank you for your help, good to know. :-)

Comment: @BrianMStafford The function `FolderExists` is used and needed for the `MakeFolder` procedure. So it should not be deleted. But in `FolderCreate` it is better to go with BigBen's solution as there is a `fso` created anyway. So `FolderExists` would create another one which is not necessary.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, it is currently used but could easily be replaced with `fso.FolderExists`.

Comment: @BrianMStafford yes, it could. But it would highly depend on how the rest of the code looks like. Using functions is not a bad thing and it might be used in some other code too. So better check twice.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I love functions, in fact they are a great thing.  But this function serves no purpose, it is only a wrapper for single line of fso code.  So yes, check twice.  If this was my code, I would immediately refactor to get rid of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @BigBen, @BrianMStafford for your help.  I managed to come up with this which works. This creates 10 subfolders within the master folder which is in a cell specified location.  It then creates a further subfolder in folder 1.

For some reason my companies security has a issue opening the files created by the code where there name is not from a cell.  So i plan on moving all the other folder names to a range of cells with hope this works.

After this when i work out how to do it, i plan on getting it to open the folder the user would use first. In my case this is the last created folder.  Hope this helps someone :-)

```
'requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub MakeFolder()

Dim strFolder As String, strPath As String

strFolder = CleanName(Range("C31")) ' assumes folder name is in C31
strPath = Range("C44") ' assumes path name is in C44

If Not FolderExists(strPath) Then
'Path doesn't exist, so create full path
    FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder
Else
'Path does exist, but no quote folder
    If Not FolderExists(strPath & "\" & strFolder) Then
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "01. Customer RFQ"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "02. Design Engineering"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "03. Drawings"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "04. Costings"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "05. Schedules"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "06. Quotation"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "07. Email"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "08. MOMs"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "09. Sales Excellence"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "10. Compliance"
        FolderCreate strPath & "\" & strFolder & "\" & "01. Customer RFQ" & "\" & Range("C33")
    End If
End If

End Sub

Function FolderCreate(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderCreate = True
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    On Error GoTo DeadInTheWater
    fso.CreateFolder path ' could there be any error with this, like if the path is really screwed up?
    Exit Function
End If

DeadInTheWater:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & path & ". Check the path name and try again."
    FolderCreate = False
    Exit Function

End Function

Function FolderExists(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderExists = False
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExists = True

End Function

Function CleanName(strName As String) As String
'will clean part # name so it can be made into valid folder name
'may need to add more lines to get rid of other characters

    CleanName = Replace(strName, "/", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "*", "")

End Function
```

Comment: If you name your folders "01...", "02...",, "10..." then they will sort in the correct order in Windows Explorer, instead of 1 and 10 sorting together.