# How to save a sheet and PDF in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I created a workbook in which would be a chart to input data and stored in the same workbook. I managed to create a save path in which the PDF file would be stored but I also need in the same code the coding for saving the sheet in the same workbook as a continuation.

This is what I come up so far for only saving in the PDF format.

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="D:" & Range("H60").Value & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")
```

If somebody could help me would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "saving the sheet in the same workbook as a continuation"?

Comment: What is in H60? The file path (i.e. folder name etc.) or the file name?

Comment: What do you mean by *"in which would be a chart to input data and stored in the same workbook."*? Do you really mean a "chart" here? A chart is a graphic and you cannot input data there. Do you mean a form? Or even a UserForm?

Comment: Maybe this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61060302/excel-vba-creates-a-folder-sub-folders-and-further-sub-folders

Comment: Sorry for my bad phrasing. In "Chart" i mean like a table. The table contains cells which would be filled with information like names, describtions, time etc. So basically i want the table to be saved in two ways. First external in a specific path as a PDF file and in the same workbook where my table would be. I've added a button which deletes all the cells that would be filled and reuse the table for the next project. So at the end i would have one excel file with the saved data and on a external path i would have the table as PDF. Hope the description helps a little more :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the path is on sheet1

```
dim path as string 'path variable that stores the path

path="D:" & sheet1.Range("H60").Value & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")

'sheets to export
'they must be selected before exporting.
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2",...)).Select

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= path, _
     Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

I hope it helps you