# How to create new folder in powerpoint using VBA?

Tags: pdf, directory, powerpoint, create-directory

I'm trying to get this macro to save my powerpoint slides as pdf in new folder, that is not created beforehand. Problem is that it seems like MkDir doesn't create the root folder, but rather folder inside folder. So if I want to create brand new folder in C:\ it doesn't do it, "Run time error '76' Path not found" occurs.

```
Sub Creating_Folder()

Dim timestamp As Date
Dim PR As PrintRanges
Dim lngLast As Long
Dim lngFirst As Long
Dim savePath As String
Dim PrintPDF As Integer
Dim name As String
Dim originalHides() As Long
Dim slidesToPrint() As Variant
Dim i As Variant
Dim folderPath As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim folder As String

strPath = "C:\Powerpoint2\test_file\"

If Not FolderExists(strPath) Then
    FolderCreate strPath
End If

'Create a folder if it does not already exist, if it does, do nothing
'folderPath = "\\?\C:\Powerpoint\new_folder2"

'Check if the folder exists
'If Dir(folderPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then

    'Folder does not exist, so create it
   ' MkDir folderPath

'End If

timestamp = Now()

With ActivePresentation
    name = .Slides(2).Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Text
    savePath = strPath & Format(timestamp, "yyyymmdd-hhnn") & " - " & name & ".pdf"
    lngLast = .Slides.Count
    .PrintOptions.Ranges.ClearAll
    
    slidesToPrint = Array(2, lngLast)
    
    ReDim originalHides(1 To lngLast)
    For i = 1 To lngLast
      originalHides(i) = .Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden
      .Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = -1
    Next
    For Each i In slidesToPrint()
      .Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = 0
    Next
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Path:=savePath, _
        FixedFormatType:=ppFixedFormatTypePDF, _
        Intent:=ppFixedFormatIntentScreen, _
        FrameSlides:=msoTrue
    For i = 1 To lngLast
      .Slides(i).SlideShowTransition.Hidden = originalHides(i)
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Also added this to end

```
Function FolderCreate(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderCreate = True
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    On Error GoTo DeadInTheWater
    fso.CreateFolder path ' could there be any error with this, like if the path is really screwed up?
    Exit Function
End If

DeadInTheWater:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & path & ". Check the path name and try again."
    FolderCreate = False
    Exit Function

End Function

Function FolderExists(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderExists = False
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExists = True

End Function
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around `folderPath`. Variables should not be inside quotes.

Comment: Missing an ``\`` in between the path and the formatted date probably.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem #2. But still having problem with creating new folder

Comment: [Possibly useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803834/create-a-folder-and-sub-folder-in-excel-vba).

Comment: I think that might work, but now the problem is that I'm not too familiar with VBA, so dont know how to deal with this new error that says "error 424: Object required" in line of `If Functions.FolderExists(path) Then` I also updated the code in first post.

Comment: Should be `fso`, not `Functions`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it! Now it works like a charm!